# Using Azure B2C login to access Microsoft Graph is the social login is a Microsoft account

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, blazor, azure-ad-b2c, blazor-webassembly

I have an application (Blazor WebAssembly in my case but I believe this scenario applies to other application types as well) that uses the excellent (and convenient) [Azure B2C login services](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/overview) to allow my users to register and log in using either a local account or some social accounts. In particular, I am supporting logging in with a Microsoft account. Once a user is logged in using his Microsoft account I want to give the user the option to save content on OneDrive without the user having to provide credentials again to access the [Microsoft Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/overview).

In the returned claims after logging in using Azure B2C API I see that there is a **idp** claim (that's how I can determine if the user is logged in using a Microsoft account) and there is also a **idp_access_token** claim but it is not a valid JWT to use against the Microsoft Graph unfortunately.

**What is the nature of the *idp_access_token*? How can I use it to access the Microsoft Graph and request additional scopes?**

Answer (score 1):

Azure AD B2C receives an access token (idp_access_token) from the identity provider. Azure AD B2C uses that token to retrieve information about the user. See details [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/idp-pass-through-user-flow?pivots=b2c-user-flow).

No matter whether **idp_access_token** claim is a valid JWT, it cannot be used to access Microsoft Graph or other additional scopes. As the document has stated, it is for retrieving information about the user. Usually the embedded IdP access token is used to call the services that the IdP hosts. But Microsoft Graph data is hosted in Azure AD, not Microsoft Account side.

Currently, if you want to call Microsoft Graph API for B2C tenant, you have to follow Azure AD Authentication protocols. For example, [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow).

If you want to call you own API protected by B2C, you should choose Azure B2C Authentication protocols. For example, [OAuth 2.0 authorization code flow in Azure Active Directory B2C](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/authorization-code-flow).

Comment: Thanks. I was to call the Microsoft Graph API for a user that previously authenticated via Azure B2C using a Microsoft account (one of the social IDPs we integrate with). Because they authenticated with a Microsoft account I know that they have access to OneNote (via Microsoft Graph API). I was hoping to avoid them having to log in a second time to access the Microsoft Graph API, but your answer doesn't address this scenario. I don't want to access the B2C tenant via Graph API but OneNote. Or are you saying that I can access the user's OneNote files via Graph API and B2C tenant?

Comment: @PhilippSchmid I'm saying that sign into B2C is using **B2C Authentication protocols**. But to access personal OneNote via Microsoft Graph, you have to use **Azure AD Authentication protocols**. You cannot use a single login to achieve this requirement.

Comment: I am confused.  I have a Node.js app with Azure AD B2C authentication setup and a single Azure AD tenant as an Open ID Connect Identify Provider.  So both 'local' users and Azure AD tenant users can sign in.  I want Azure AD users to be able to make Graph API calls to their own tenant environment.  [This official repo](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/B2C-Token-Includes-AzureAD-BearerToken) seems to suggest this is possible as it specifically says it shows "how to call the Graph API of the users’ home Azure AD tenant using the issued Azure AD Bearer token".

Comment: This Microsoft blog post also seems to be saying that the purpose of having an `idp_access_token` is to call the relevant API:  https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-entra-azure-ad-blog/announcing-the-general-availability-of-two-key-features-in-azure/ba-p/566362