# Blazor Wasm Hosted. .Net 6.0. AAD and API

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, blazor, webassembly

I'm trying to put two things working at the same time and I have no luck.

In my .Net 6 Blazor WebAssembly Hosted, I can log to Azure AD accounts and it works fine following the sample:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/webassembly/hosted-with-azure-active-directory?view=aspnetcore-6.0

Also, I can log to Microsoft Graph following this:
https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-training-blazor-clientside

But what I want is to be able to have a token valid for both. I want to call to Microsoft Graph and to call to my API from the server side.

Any idea how to mix both "samples" to make it work? I think the only I need is to "mix" in the program.cs this:

```
builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ReservasSalasAuth.ServerAPI", client =>
     client.BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress))
    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>().CreateClient("ReservasSalasAuth.ServerAPI"));
```

And this:

```
builder.Services.AddScoped(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri("https://graph.microsoft.com") });
```

But I have no luck...

Comment: https://github.com/AzureAD/microsoft-identity-web/blob/master/tools/app-provisioning-tool/README.md

Comment: Thanks but it seems it's not problem of app configuration (at least I think it because the following...)

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigation...I realize that the order in the AddMsalAuthentication makes the difference...

```
    builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
    var ApiScope = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiScope");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(ApiScope);
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "appRole";
    var scopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("GraphScopes");

    foreach (var scope in scopes.Split(';'))
    {
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(scope);
    }
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, GraphUserAccountFactory>();
```

This way, I take the Scope for the Api an it works the Api call but not the Graph call.

```
builder.Services.AddMsalAuthentication<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount>(options =>
{
    builder.Configuration.Bind("AzureAd", options.ProviderOptions.Authentication);
   
    options.UserOptions.RoleClaim = "appRole";
    var scopes = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("GraphScopes");

    foreach (var scope in scopes.Split(';'))
    {
        options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(scope);
    }
    var ApiScope = builder.Configuration.GetValue<string>("ApiScope");
    options.ProviderOptions.DefaultAccessTokenScopes.Add(ApiScope);
}).AddAccountClaimsPrincipalFactory<RemoteAuthenticationState, CustomUserAccount, GraphUserAccountFactory>();
```

And changing the order I put the scopes, it works the Graph call but not the API call.

Any ideas to make it work both two?

Comment: You should create one `HtmlClient` configured for each "scope". They should be stored in the `IHttpClientFactory` by "scope name". To get the appropriate client for the call you Inject the `IHttpClientFactory` not `HttpClient` and use the factory Create method with the "scope name".

Comment: Your comment drove me to the solution. Two HttpClient and each one configure with the BaseAddress and scopes needed.
Thank you @BrianParker!!

Comment: can you post snippet of what did ? I have same issue and can't get past InvalidAuthenticationToken on resource I am trying to access. Both work seperately , but not together.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue. You CAN'T use Msal to operate on two different authority.
So if you want to use graph and your api in the same time you need to chose One to use Msal with and for the other one you need to make the entire requirement yourself. So ask for authorize code, use it to get new access token and then use this new one for your second Http client as bearer in the header.

So yes you cannot achieve what you want with only one login.

Here look at last comment from Allen Wu
https://stackoverflow.com/a/65694725